# Typescript - How to check destructured values instead using dot notation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I have an async-await handler:

```js
const asyncHandler = async <Type>(
  promise: Promise<Type>
): Promise<[Type, null] | [null, string]> => {
  try {
    const response = await promise
    return [response, null]
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return [null, error]
  }
}

export default asyncHandler
```

This give me no error:

```js
import asyncHandler from './async_handler'

interface Success {
  payload: string
}

interface MyError {
  payload: undefined
  error?: true
}

const fetchData = async (): Promise<Success | MyError> => {
  const fetchDataResponse = await asyncHandler<string>(
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('potato'), 200)
    })
  )

  if (fetchDataResponse[1]) return { payload: undefined, error: true }

  return { payload: fetchDataResponse[0] }
}

export default fetchData
```

but this give type error because is expecting response to be string or undefined but response is string or null

```js
import asyncHandler from './async_handler'

interface Success {
  payload: string
}

interface MyError {
  payload: undefined
  error?: true
}

const fetchData = async (): Promise<Success | MyError> => {
  const [response, error] = await asyncHandler<string>(
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('potato'), 200)
    })
  )

  if (error) return { payload: undefined, error: true }

  return { payload: response } // Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2322)
}

export default fetchData
```

I know that response is not set only to string type because those two variables are independent now but is there a way to make the second example work like the first one?

Comment: Just a suggestion - you should use `console.error()` instead of `console.log()` in your `catch` block

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'll use! :D

Answer (score 0):

Found that this is expected!
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32639

Related answer:
[Typescript type fails if object is destructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256733/typescript-type-fails-if-object-is-destructed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `fetchDataResponse[0]` for `null`

Next as you described you interface `MyError`, `payload` can be only `undefined`. For interface `Success`, `payload` can be only `string`, but you want to return `response` which can be `string` or `null`

Making `payload` optional, you will achieve what you want

```
interface MyError {
  payload?: null
  error?: true
}
```